# iOS Firebase Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException this request has been neutered

Tags: ios, firebase

I have a exception on firebase console

Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
this request has been neutered - you can't call -sendResponse: twice nor after encoding it
+[_CFXNotificationTokenRegistration keyCallbacks]

here is the trace

```
Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  MyApp                 0x104cc16d8 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 376 (CLSProcess.c:376)
1  MyApp                 0x104cc1ac0 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 407 (CLSProcess.c:407)
2  MyApp                 0x104cb17c4 CLSHandler + 26 (CLSHandler.m:26)
3  MyApp                 0x104cbfcec __CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke + 198 (CLSException.mm:198)
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x2254257d4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x2253d3c1c _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
6  MyApp                 0x104cbf794 CLSExceptionRecord + 205 (CLSException.mm:205)
7  MyApp                 0x104cbf5c8 CLSExceptionRecordNSException + 102 (CLSException.mm:102)
8  MyApp                 0x104cbf1ec CLSTerminateHandler() + 258 (CLSException.mm:258)
9  libc++abi.dylib                0x224bb4838 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x224bb48c4 std::terminate() + 84
11 libobjc.A.dylib                0x224bbfd5c _destroyAltHandlerList + 10
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x2254257e8 _dispatch_client_callout + 36
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x2253d3c1c _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
14 BaseBoard                      0x2281633b0 -[BSAction sendResponse:withCompletion:] + 132
15 UIKitCore                      0x251eeca10 -[UIHandleRemoteNotificationAction sendResponse:] + 144
16 UIKitCore                      0x25230e8e0 __91-[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_3.2600 + 72
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x225424a38 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x2254257d4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x2253d3008 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1068
20 CoreFoundation                 0x22597832c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
21 CoreFoundation                 0x225973264 __CFRunLoopRun + 1924
22 CoreFoundation                 0x2259727c0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
23 GraphicsServices               0x227b7379c GSEventRunModal + 104
24 UIKitCore                      0x2522f7c38 UIApplicationMain + 212
25 MyApp                            0x104a62744 main + 22 (PostDetailsCommentsCellConfigurator.swift:22)
26 libdyld.dylib                  0x2254368e0 start + 4
```

I can't reproduce bug on my iPhone or simulator

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. Still couldn't find a solution. Have you fixed this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60931878/fatal-exception-nsinternalinconsistencyexception-crash-on-ios