# Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException Crash on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics, remote-notifications

Been trying to recreate and research about this issue for days now and I'm not going anywhere. Here's the stack trace. Can anyone shed light on to what's happening? I take that it has something to do with remote notifications. The issue started a while back when I installed the firebase sdk. Back then it wasn't a lot but now, crashes seem to happen more often than usual.

Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
this request has been neutered - you can't call -sendResponse: twice nor after encoding it
+[_CFXNotificationTokenRegistration keyCallbacks]

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1c2726ab8 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1c192bd00 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1c263be90 +[_CFXNotificationTokenRegistration keyCallbacks]
3  Foundation                     0x1c3117cfc -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
4  BaseBoard                      0x1c4f2e664 __40-[BSAction sendResponse:withCompletion:]_block_invoke
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x1c2135888 _dispatch_client_callout
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1c2142404 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete
7  BaseBoard                      0x1c4ee2b84 -[BSAction sendResponse:withCompletion:]
8  UIKitCore                      0x1ef72bf84 -[UIHandleRemoteNotificationAction sendResponse:]
9  UIKitCore                      0x1efb69028 __91-[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_3.2678
10 UIKitCore                      0x1efb69b4c __125-[UIApplication _updateStateRestorationArchiveForBackgroundEvent:saveState:exitIfCouldNotRestoreState:updateSnapshot:canvas:]_block_invoke_2
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x1c2134308 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x1c2135888 _dispatch_client_callout
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x1c214173c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
14 CoreFoundation                 0x1c26b6734 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
15 CoreFoundation                 0x1c26b13e4 __CFRunLoopRun
16 CoreFoundation                 0x1c26b0964 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
17 GraphicsServices               0x1c48f1d8c GSEventRunModal
18 UIKitCore                      0x1efb51758 UIApplicationMain
19 XXXX                       0x1023e1480 main + 26 (AppDelegate.swift:26)
20 libdyld.dylib                  0x1c216cfd8 start

Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  XXXX                       0x102692000 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4305018880
1  XXXX                       0x1026923e8 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4305019880
2  XXXX                       0x102681c60 CLSHandler + 4304952416
3  XXXX                       0x102690604 __CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke + 4305012228
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x1c2135888 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x1c2142404 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 60
6  XXXX                       0x102690070 CLSExceptionRecord + 4305010800
7  XXXX                       0x10268fe9c CLSExceptionRecordNSException + 4305010332
8  XXXX                       0x10268fa90 CLSTerminateHandler() + 4305009296
9  libc++abi.dylib                0x1c19209cc std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x1c1920a40 std::terminate() + 60
11 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1c192c09c _destroyAltHandlerList + 14
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x1c213589c _dispatch_client_callout + 40
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x1c2142404 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 60
14 BaseBoard                      0x1c4ee2b84 -[BSAction sendResponse:withCompletion:] + 148
15 UIKitCore                      0x1ef72bf84 -[UIHandleRemoteNotificationAction sendResponse:] + 148
16 UIKitCore                      0x1efb69028 __91-[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_3.2678 + 76
17 UIKitCore                      0x1efb69b4c __125-[UIApplication _updateStateRestorationArchiveForBackgroundEvent:saveState:exitIfCouldNotRestoreState:updateSnapshot:canvas:]_block_invoke_2 + 264
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x1c2134308 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x1c2135888 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x1c214173c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1012
21 CoreFoundation                 0x1c26b6734 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
22 CoreFoundation                 0x1c26b13e4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1888
23 CoreFoundation                 0x1c26b0964 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
24 GraphicsServices               0x1c48f1d8c GSEventRunModal + 108
25 UIKitCore                      0x1efb51758 UIApplicationMain + 216
26 XXXX                       0x1023e1480 main + 26 (AppDelegate.swift:26)
27 libdyld.dylib                  0x1c216cfd8 start + 4
```

Comment: Adding a trace to the question is a good thing but some further troubleshooting would help. It appears it's crashing in or around send response - probably within the closure. Have you added some print statements to try to isolate the section of code that's crashing? Do you know which section it is? If so, can you include it in the question? Are you doing any notifications with Firebase? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Which frame is getting blamed in Crashlytics front end?

Comment: If there's any confusion about Crashlytics frames appearing in these stacktraces, this is covered in this doc: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html#crashlytics-frames-appearing-in-crashes

"...This means that in the case of an exception, the “crashing” thread will always look like it is running Crashlytics code. This is normal, and is just an artifact of how we capture and present the stack traces at the time of exception."